# How to use Bokeh datetimetickformatter to customize ticks

Tags: python, bokeh

I am relatively new to python and I am using bokeh to create a html file that plots some timeseries data.

I would like to format the x-axis ticks as "DD/MM HH:SS". I am writing a simplified version of the code:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, save, show
from bokeh.models import DatetimeTickFormatter
import datetime as dt
t=[dt.datetime(2017, 1, 9, 16, 14, 10),dt.datetime(2017, 1, 9, 16, 15, 20)]
Temp=[200,210]
output_file("Burner SPC test.html")
p1=figure(title="Tip1 TC", x_axis_label="Time", y_axis_label="Temp Diff", x_axis_type="datetime")
p1.line(t,Temp)
p1.xaxis.formatter=DatetimeTickFormatter(formats=dict(
days=["%??"],
months=["%??"],
hours=["%???"],
minutes=["%???"])) #not sure how to format here to get the desired output
show(p1)
```

Any help is highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved it using `"%m/%d %H:%M"` for all the fields: months, days, hours, minutes:

```
p1.xaxis.formatter=DatetimeTickFormatter(formats=dict(
    days=["%m/%d %H:%M"],
    months=["%m/%d %H:%M"],
    hours=["%m/%d %H:%M"],
    minutes=["%m/%d %H:%M"]
))
```

Initially I was trying to use `"%m"` for months, `"%d"` for days, `"%H"` for hours and `"%M"` for minutes but since I want the same format across all those scales, they all need to be configured the same.

Answer (score 4):

DateTimeTickFormatter is not expecting dicts anymore (as mentioned by bigreddot [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41836196/bokeh-datetimetickformatter)). With my version of Bokeh (1.0.4) it worked by removing "formats=dict()" and providing the format strings.

```
p1.xaxis.formatter=DatetimeTickFormatter(days="%m/%d %H:%M",
months="%m/%d %H:%M",
hours="%m/%d %H:%M",
minutes="%m/%d %H:%M")
```

You could do both. Use the same format string for all of them, or use individual format strings. The Format of the axis adjusts when zooming in.

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, save, Show
from bokeh.models import DatetimeTickFormatter
import datetime as dt
import datetime as dt
t=[dt.datetime(2017, 1, 9, 16, 14, 10),dt.datetime(2017, 1, 10, 17, 15, 20)]
Temp=[200,210]
output_file("Burner SPC test.html")
p1=figure(title="Tip1 TC", x_axis_label="Time", y_axis_label="Temp Diff", x_axis_type="datetime")
p1.line(t,Temp)
p1.xaxis.formatter=DatetimeTickFormatter(days="%m/%d",
hours="%H",
minutes="%H:%M")
show(p1)
```