# Bokeh datetimetickformatter

Tags: python-2.7, bokeh

I'm have some trouble with the `DatetimeTickFormatter` object from `Bokeh`. Plots randomly won't generate/update.

I have been searching and found this post at `Bokeh`, where it states that [`Plot not shown if DatetimeTickFormatter partially defined`](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/5234). I need some help with how to define it properly. Currently I'm doing this:

```
from bokeh.models.formatters import DatetimeTickFormatter
from bokeh.plotting import figure
DTF =  DatetimeTickFormatter()
DTF.hours = ["%H:%M"]
DTF.days = ["%d/%m/%Y"]
DTF.months = ["%d/%m/%Y"]
DTF.years = ["%d/%m/%Y"]
```

and

```
p = figure()
p.xaxis.formatter = DTF
```

How should I define DTF “properly”?

Comment: That's an old issue, are you using an old version of Bokeh? `DatetimeTickFormatter` used to be configured with a "dict" and it was improperly configured if you set a new value that didn't have *all* the right keys/values. But recent changes just made all the necessary keys and values be properties, that always have at least default values, always. So it's not possible to misconfigure it anymore, at least not in the way described in the issue you link.  Do you have a complete example that can be tested? Can you describe your problem in better detail?

Comment: Im Im using bokeh 0.12.4, i think thats the last version. I tryed defining it with a dict, but i it dossent solve it and i get a deprecated warrning. I tryed to set all the "keys" according what i think is correct. As given here http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/formatters.htm

Comment: Right, that's what I said. The `dict` is the old (bad, easy to misconfigure) method. It's been deprecated removed. I was not suggesting that you use a dict. It's possible there is a bug, or maybe it's a user-error. It's impossible to say more without a complete example to run and test with.

Comment: Just a feeling, time values are saved as strings in a database (sqlite3), i import using Pandas.read_sql_query() and convert the time colum using pandas.to_datetime() with a format string matching my data format. Im unsure how to make a more complete example.

Comment: "Solved" the issue with creating a new DTF object everytime i make a new figure.

Comment: It would be unusual to share a tick formatter between different plots so I would regard that as both acceptable and correct.